# Checkpoints for a stored procedures with exception handling

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exception, automation

**Given** : 
 1. I have a proc (**Parent**) that calls another proc (**Child**) which contains multiple operations like updating multiple columns like total_visits, total_revenue, total_items_sold, etc.
 2. I have a table called **Event_Log** with columns **[proc_name, start_time, end_time, exit_status, error_message]** which is meant to store the status of each procedure *Child* and *Parent*.

**Objective** : To implement a *Checkpoint based* methodology to track the execution of a stored procedure where it keeps updating a checkpoint variable on successful completion of any procedure/operation. It must also update the **Event_Log** table in order to *document the progress of the stored procs execution*.

**What I've read so far** :

1. `GET DIAGNOSTICS` documentation
2. Something like `DECLARE CONTINUE/EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION`.

Find the sample code to work with :

```
drop procedure if exists Parent;
delimiter $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE Parent(value INT)
BEGIN
/* some event logic*/
CALL Child(12);
/* some event logic*/
INSERT INTO Event_Log(info...)
END$$
DELIMITER;

drop procedure if exists Child;
delimiter $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE Child(value INT)
BEGIN
/* ---- some event logic ------ 

checkpoint 1 :
operation 1 

checkpoint 2 :
operation 2

checkpoint 3 :
operation 3
*/

/* after execution of all the procs */
INSERT INTO Event_Log(info...)
END$$
DELIMITER;


CALL Parent(123);
```

So, if the `checkpoint 2` in `Child` failed then the Event_Log must have the entry of

1. Parent failed - error message
2. Child failed - error message, checkpoint number, error-msg of the SQL Exceptions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @wchiquito Please help!!

Comment: @eggyal Please help!!